# Why is Bootstrap Toasts transparent but sticks to the content?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, toast

I have a Bootstrap 5 site and a Toasts that shows when the visitor is offline.

My Toasts is at the bottom of the page and it is fixed. If you go to the page and the Toasts is on a button, it covers the button even though it is not displayed. How to make the Toast disappear without it disturbing the page by putting itself on top of the content ? In the example of the Bootstrap document there is no such problem.

index.html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr" class="h-100">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body class="position-relative d-flex flex-column bg-dark text-white text-center" data-bs-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar" data-bs-offset="85" tabindex="0">

    <div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x mb-3">
      <div id="updateToast" class="toast d-none" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-repeat text-success" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M11.534 7h3.932a.25.25 0 0 1 .192.41l-1.966 2.36a.25.25 0 0 1-.384 0l-1.966-2.36a.25.25 0 0 1 .192-.41zm-11 2h3.932a.25.25 0 0 0 .192-.41L2.692 6.23a.25.25 0 0 0-.384 0L.342 8.59A.25.25 0 0 0 .534 9z"/>
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3c-1.552 0-2.94.707-3.857 1.818a.5.5 0 1 1-.771-.636A6.002 6.002 0 0 1 13.917 7H12.9A5.002 5.002 0 0 0 8 3zM3.1 9a5.002 5.002 0 0 0 8.757 2.182.5.5 0 1 1 .771.636A6.002 6.002 0 0 1 2.083 9H3.1z"/>
          </svg>
          <strong class="me-auto">Mise à jour disponible</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body text-start text-dark">
          Cliquez ICI pour mettre à jour.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="offlineToast" class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="toast-header">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-wifi-off text-danger" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M10.706 3.294A12.545 12.545 0 0 0 8 3C5.259 3 2.723 3.882.663 5.379a.485.485 0 0 0-.048.736.518.518 0 0 0 .668.05A11.448 11.448 0 0 1 8 4c.63 0 1.249.05 1.852.148l.854-.854zM8 6c-1.905 0-3.68.56-5.166 1.526a.48.48 0 0 0-.063.745.525.525 0 0 0 .652.065 8.448 8.448 0 0 1 3.51-1.27L8 6zm2.596 1.404.785-.785c.63.24 1.227.545 1.785.907a.482.482 0 0 1 .063.745.525.525 0 0 1-.652.065 8.462 8.462 0 0 0-1.98-.932zM8 10l.933-.933a6.455 6.455 0 0 1 2.013.637c.285.145.326.524.1.75l-.015.015a.532.532 0 0 1-.611.09A5.478 5.478 0 0 0 8 10zm4.905-4.905.747-.747c.59.3 1.153.645 1.685 1.03a.485.485 0 0 1 .047.737.518.518 0 0 1-.668.05 11.493 11.493 0 0 0-1.811-1.07zM9.02 11.78c.238.14.236.464.04.66l-.707.706a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0l-.707-.707c-.195-.195-.197-.518.04-.66A1.99 1.99 0 0 1 8 11.5c.374 0 .723.102 1.021.28zm4.355-9.905a.53.53 0 0 1 .75.75l-10.75 10.75a.53.53 0 0 1-.75-.75l10.75-10.75z"/>
          </svg>
          <strong class="me-auto">Vous êtes hors-ligne</strong>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="toast-body text-start text-dark">
          Les informations de cette page peuvent être obsolètes.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="toasts.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

toasts.js :

```
window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
  var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#offlineToast'))
  var toastList = toastElList.map(function(toastEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl)
  });
  toastList.forEach(toast => toast.show());
});

window.addEventListener('online', () => {
  var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#offlineToast'))
  var toastList = toastElList.map(function(toastEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl)
  });
  toastList.forEach(toast => toast.hide());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the class `hide` to your toast element like

```
 <div id="offlineToast" class="toast hide" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">...</div>
```